# how to change same ng-repeat values and show only select values angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

**UPDATED**
i want to change ng-repeat values separately, from shown single input text box,
i'm trying to bind inputbox to label, but all values binding together, can u please tell me how to change only selected div values, i don't want to use ng-repeat to add values, pls tell me without using ng-repeat in start **add again** you can use ng-repeat further functions, form should be shown in certain position to change values in input box to label, can u pls solve this to me..??
[Working DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/4fjW1TdVAmnqql2x3VjO?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('AddCtrl', function ($scope, $compile) {

     $scope.items = [];
        $scope.add_New = function (index) {
        var itemhtml = '<div ng-click="select()" class="content">//click here first// <div ng-repeat="item in items">{{$index + 1}}. {{item.name}}</div></div>';
        var item = $compile(itemhtml)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('drop')).append(item);
          };
        $scope.add = function () {
          $scope.items.push({ 
            name: "hi"
          });
        };
        $scope.select = function(){
          $scope.showItem = true;
        }
});
```

```css
.add{
  position: absolute; height: auto; width: 200px; left: 0; right: auto; top: 0; bottom: 0;
}
.show{
  position: absolute; width: auto; left: 200px; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    border:1px solid red;
float:right;
}
.content{
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
          <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AddCtrl">
 <div class="add"><button ng-click="add_New($index)">add Again</button>
    <div id="drop">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="showItem" class="show">
          <div ng-repeat="item in items">
            {{$index + 1}}.<input type="text" ng-model="item.name">
            </div>
            <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>

          </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what is your desired output.Can you please make it more clear.

Comment: @Viplock ..if we clicked **add again** button, have to append certain divs, if we click any div in appended divs, a form will be opened(where would be **add** button), if i added and entered any values from that add button,, inputs are adding to all divs and binding text in all divs together, i want to change only selected div values

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your way of thinking of html elements. Forget about jQuery and focus on angular-way.

First, you don't need to deal with new html elements. We need to get rid of that `var itemhtml` and `$compile(itemhtml)`. Second, you need to change your data model.

. * UPDATED BELOW HERE * .

See updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/V9jAoMsoDxYOvcxjbsv8?p=preview) for details.

Your controller will be like that:

```
app.controller('AddCtrl', function ($scope, $compile) {

  $scope.itemGroups = [];

  $scope.addGroup = function () {
    $scope.itemGroups.push({ 
      items: []
    });
  };
  $scope.addItem = function (itemGroup) {
    itemGroup.items.push({ 
      name: "hi"
    });
  };
  $scope.editItemGroup = function (itemGroup) {
    $scope.selectedItemGroup = itemGroup;
  };
});
```

And your html should make use of ng-repeat like that:

```
<div ng-repeat="itemGroup in itemGroups" class="add">
  <button ng-if="itemGroup != selectedItemGroup"
          ng-click="editItemGroup(itemGroup)">Edit</button>
  <div ng-repeat="item in itemGroup.items">
    {{$index + 1}}.<label ng-bind="item.name"></label>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="addItem(itemGroup)">Add</button>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in selectedItemGroup.items">
  {{$index + 1}}.<input type="text" ng-model="item.name">
</div>
<button ng-click="editItemGroup(null)" ng-if="selectedItemGroup">Done editing</button>
```

Comment: ok thank you .. i tried like that i get the result, but my requirement is no need to add inputs directly,, i have to add inputs from a single shown form,, if i click add button then only have to add input fields to selected divs..

Comment: i updated my code.. can u pls check it once that what is my requirement exactly??

Comment: than you.. u really done a great job,,, but i have a small doubt,, in ur code in **addGroup** click function u have used push event using ng-repeat, Is it possible if i use Append event there,, i'm not getting result,, my total add inputs are based on Append event only,, thats why i'm getting issues.. can u tell me how can i use **append** instead of **push & ng-repeat** in addGroup function ...

Comment: You're still thinking DOM-manipulation-way bro. Think Angular-way. You can make it work, just try a bit harder. If you really need to manipulate DOM, you can write directives.

Comment: hmm :( .. u r telling fact,, but my requirement will be like that only,, actually what my requirement is ? i have to add name, email and mobile no and etc fields from left side if user want to add name or email in form it will be shown in main page dynamically if user click on that field, settings page will be opened on right side,from where i have to change each text values,, if i used ng-repeat i cannot able to see saved data in form, thats why i am using append to add values :(