# How to select an Edit button with no text of an ng-repeat element?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a Form builder, where i select the fieldtype from ng-repeat and the element appears in the canvas. I want to click the Edit button of that element on the canvas. Clicking the edit button shows few more fields to enter. But all the elements are in ng-repeat and the button have no id,name,model.
[image]

[image]

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34783140/how-to-change-same-ng-repeat-values-and-show-only-select-values-angularjs

Hope this will help you

Comment: @MaheshShahane the link you shared is for adding elements to existing div tags, but in my case i want to perform action on the existing 'edit' button like click but not able to find locator of that button using protractor.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should do the trick:

```
function editBuilder(builderName) {
  // select title of a builder which is span
  const title = element(by.cssContainingText('.h4', builderName));

  // get root form element (parent element)
  const root = title.element(by.xpath('..'));

  // get edit button 
  const editButton = root.$('[ng-click="editFields($index)"]')

  // click or something
  return editButton.click(); 
}
```

And then you can call this function like so:

```
editBuilder('Text Field').then(...);
```

Comment: The xpath of the edit button is :
//*[@id="tab-content-11"]/div/md-content/form/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/md-content/div[1]/div/button[1]
ID is changing everytime the page is accessed.

Comment: don't use such long xpath, this wont work this way, just select edit button in the same block, where block title is. passing `..` to `xpath` returns you parent element

Comment: i am not able to select the edit button of the second ng-repeat element.

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to get select the 1st ng-repeat element by using the following code:

`element(by.xpath("//button[@class='md-icon-button md-button md-ink-ripple md-default-theme']")).click();
element(by.name("label")).clear().sendKeys("admin");`

Answer (score 0):

If there is more than one edit button, you could just locate them like this:

```
element.all(by.css('.icon.icon-pencil.s20')).get(<index>);
```

index starts at 0
If there is only one, then:

```
element(by.css('.icon.icon-pencil.s20'));
```